# Tag image for other browsers like google-chrome

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, questions

I have seen `google-chrome` tag with an image on it,

[alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/6461/gogchr.jpg](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/6461/gogchr.jpg)

But firefox and internet explorer doesn't seem to have images on their tags...

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/3379/firefoxi.jpg](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/3379/firefoxi.jpg)
[alt text http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/1884/13382628.jpg](http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/1884/13382628.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag images are sponsered - in other words someone has to pay to have a tag sponsered with an image on it.  You can get details on the sponser by going to the tag's page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome

If you'd like to see images on the firefox or ie tags, [contact advertising info](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?ZoneID=0&BannerID=323&AdvertiserID=5&CampaignID=194&Task=Click&SiteID=1) and express your interest.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sponsor